# Сайт обновляется, когда выполняет команду socket.emit

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, сокет, socket.io

Есть сайт, который взаимодействует с сервером по `socket.io`. Когда сайт отправляет `socket.emit` на сервер, после отправки он тут же обновляется, хотя подобной команды в коде нет. Как это можно исправить?

Также есть подозрение, что страница обновляется, когда заканчивается скрипт, а не работает `socket.emit`. Но в таком случае вопрос тот же.

Я думал, что это связано с отправкой формы, но если я удалю `socket.emit` , который не имеет никакого отношения к форме, то все станет нормально

Код:

```js
socket.on('response', (json) => {
//какой-то код
socket.emit('indexMessage', readedMessages);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2.3.0/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Уберите socket.emit и посмотрите на поведение. Возможно код работает с формой и отправляет ее, перегружая, по умолчанию, страницу

Comment: @SwaD, уже пробовал, в этом случае все хорошо, но на сервер ничего не отправляется